# BSD route(8) MAN page bug

Tags: freebsd, route, man

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=route

> Route is a utility used to manually
>   manipulate the network routing tables.
>   It normally is not needed, as a system
>   routing table management daemon such
>   as routed(8), should tend to this
>   task.

...

> **BUGS**
>
> The first paragraph may have slightly exaggerated routed(8)'s abilities.

Is this really a "bug", or some developer's attempt at humour?

Comment: Do you really have to ask?

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked.

Comment: Reasonable question. Note to documenters: Don't assume everyone will know your inside jokes or innuendos.

Comment: From other FreeBSD man pages: - [chat(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chat&format=html)
`COPYRIGHT The chat program is in public domain. This is not the GNU public license. If it breaks then you get to keep both pieces.` [tunefs(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tunefs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE&format=html)
`BUGS This utility should work on active file systems. To change the root file system, the system must be rebooted after the file system is tuned.` and of course  `You can tune a file system, but you cannot tune a fish`

Comment: How dare you forget to mention `asr-manpages`!

Comment: FreeBSD is known for it's humorous comments in source code and man pages. It's obviously not readable for everyone :)

Comment: That 'tune a filesystem' remark is also in the HP-UX man page.

Comment: @Grahamux That `tune a filesystem` remark is in nearly every `tunefs(8)` manpage I've ever encountered. It's one of the oldest *nix manpage jokes known to man. :)

Comment: @voretaq7 The `tune a fish` line was added to 4.2BSD sometime in 1983; they didn't keep good versioning back then, so the exact date and author is lost to history. It is however, the source. The line was copied to HP-UX and SunOS 4.x (and likely others) from BSD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`routed` is a RIP daemon, which as any network administrator knows, is not very effective at creating efficient routing tables. It works great for simple environments with only a few routers.

For anything more complicated than that I'd recommend Quagga or Xorp, which both support a variety of routing protocols like OSPF, ISIS (experimental to a degree), BGP and more.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that `routed` was a RIP daemon. Makes sense now.